# Searching for the text in VBA code (in which line)

Tags: excel, vba, search, line

I wonder how to search each line in VBA module and get the number of any line where text was found. I've figured out something like this:

```
Sub addProcedure()

Dim vbProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim vbComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim vbCode As VBIDE.CodeModule

Dim strSearchPhrase As String
Dim strModuleName As String
Dim intLinesNr As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim intFoundLine As Integer

strModuleName = "Test"

Set vbProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set vbComp = vbProj.VBComponents(strModuleName)
Set vbCode = vbComp.CodeModule

intLinesNr = vbCode.CountOfLines


For i = 1 To intLinesNr
  If vbCode.Find(strSearchPhrase, i, 1, -1, -1) Then
    intFoundLine = i
    Exit For
  End If
Next i

If foundline <> 0 Then MsgBox "Text found in " & intFoundLine & " line."


Set vbComp = Nothing
Set vbProj = Nothing
Set vbCode = Nothing
End Sub
```

And it returns Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch in:

```
If vbCode.Find(strSearchPhrase, i, 1, -1, -1) Then
```

Any others ideas how to do that?

Comment: What is in strSearchPhrase? and where is this set? If you produce the error and then type "? strSearchPhrase" into the immediate window what does that display?

Comment: I forgot to put it into module, strSearchPhrase is just a text, which I'm looking for, so it can be:

    strSearchPhrase = "Test string"

Answer (score 4):

Maybe change `Dim i As Integer` to `Dim i As Long` will resolve mismatch error?

> The CodeModule object has a Find method that you can use to search for text within the code module. The Find method accepts ByRef Long parameters.

source -> http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx